# Passing data to from one controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to pass value and display from ViewController1 to ViewController2, when I go to ViewController2. The data did not display on the view. But I check po data.odrNum it has the value in it.

ViewController1

```
ViewController2 *data = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
data.odrNum = [respondData valueForKey:@"orderCode"];
```

ViewController2.h

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *odrNum`;

ViewController2.m

```
self.orderConNum.text = self.odrNum;
```

And this is the way I present my ViewController2

```
 UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;
    OrderDetailsViewController *detail = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "OrderDetailsViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Comment: Did you check your textfield outlet connection?

Comment: @jegadeesh yes, all was connected.

Comment: you have to check value is comming in self.odrNum in ViewController2?

Comment: How do you present the `ViewController2`?

Comment: can you show ur code a bit more?

Comment: try this                                                                                          
                                                                                            
ViewController2 *vc2=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController2"];
vc2.odrNum = [respondData valueForKey:@"orderCode"]
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];

Comment: Try using prepareForSegue method to send data

Comment: @Larme I've added how I present the VC2 code on above

Comment: @ravi.p it won't work for me

Comment: @Birendra value in self.odrNum show nil

Comment: @Edmund check my answer and also read comment that i put its helps you in future .

Comment: @Edmund print this value of [respondData valueForKey:@"orderCode"]; before passing it

Comment: @ravi.p got value in there

Comment: @Edmund so check in secondVC cause you are assigning a value so may be you are reassign the value in it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass data when you push viewcontroller .

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;
OrderDetailsViewController *detail = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @ "OrderDetailsViewController"];

detail.odrNum = [respondData valueForKey:@"orderCode"];  // this line you must put when you want to pass data. 

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: put break point on this line 
 detail.odrNum = [respondData valueForKey:@"orderCode"]; and check did you get any value from this [respondData valueForKey:@"orderCode"]; @Edmund

Comment: it show nil value

Comment: then you must have to get that value that you want to pass to next controller for testing just pass static value like detail.odrNum = @"Testing "; @Edmund and check did you get value testing on next controller.

Comment: Yes, if I use detail.odrNum = @"Testing, VC2 will work

Comment: @Edmund when you got your response from server at that time just store that reponse to one varible that Nssting put it global and when you want to pass data just pass that string varible so you easily send a value to next controller. hope you will clear with my answer . any problem or issue just put comment,

Comment: I got it, appreciate for your help

Comment: @Edmund always happy for help every one.

Comment: who give me down vote and why you give it ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using a [sharedSingleton](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/05jubyjir8zykkl/AACJwjHDE7PEndnwY0DRuUyHa?dl=0):

In the dropbox file is the `sharedSingleton` files I use.

In the `Changables.h` file you can **add the variables** you want to use and you can **import** it on the `UIViewControllers` you want to use.

**To set this you only have to use:**

```
[Changables sharedSingleton].yourVariable = @"my variable data"
```

**and to get the data back you can just use**

```
[Changables sharedSingleton].yourVariable.
```

I have used this to use custom Objects as well.

Comment: please format your answer for better understanding..

Comment: @lalithkumar thank you